# Code restricted to dashboard, running unexpectedly in the frontend (pre_get_post and admin-ajax.php)

Tags: filters, ajax, media-library, dashboard

I have realised that a `pre_get_post` filter in my `functions.php` is spoiling the default behaviour of other modules running (ajax) in the frontend **while user is logged in**.

What I want to achieve is to filter media library content in the dashboard to prevent non admin content to appear in the media library. So I have setup a filter `pre_get_post` in a way that when non admin users are accessing the media library, content will be filtered. This runs perfectly.

The problem occurs because this filter is applied to the dashboard media library loading module (namely `admin-ajax.php`) and for unknown reasons it looks like the filter is being applied also when the user is navigating in the frontend, (**while logged in**), and Ajax navigation in the frontend will suffer from this.

I wonder if is there a solution to stop this, ensuring that filter will really be applied only when the user is in the dashboard. I have attempted to stuff as much as possible conditions to stop running the code when user is not in the dashboard but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's the offending code in functions.php:

```
    $url_split = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // get current URI to ensure the filter is only applied when navigating in the dashboard

    $user = wp_get_current_user();   
    if ( is_admin() && !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) && strtolower($url_split[1]) == "wp-admin"){
        add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_role');
    }

    // ********** post & media lists filtered by user role & category ****************
function posts_for_current_role($query) {
global $students_allowed_cat;
global $teachers_allowed_cat;
global $pagenow;


        $user = wp_get_current_user();

        if( 'edit.php' == $pagenow   ){
            if ($query->get('cat') == '0' || IsNullOrEmptyString($query->get('cat')) || !count($_GET) ){
                if ( in_array( 'teacher', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
                    //The user has the "teacher" role
                    $filtered_cat = $teachers_allowed_cat;
                }
                if ( in_array( 'student', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
                    //The user has the "student" role
                    $filtered_cat = $students_allowed_cat;
                }
                $query->set('cat',  $filtered_cat);
            }
        }
        if (in_array( $pagenow, array( 'upload.php', 'admin-ajax.php')  ) ){
                // hide admin media for non-admin users
                $query->set('author',  '-1'); // **** OFFENDING!!!
                // log to a file what page is applying the filter
                $file = 'c:\temp\log.txt';
                $runningpage = $pagenow."\n";
                file_put_contents($file, $runningpage , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                // unbelievable but the log file will show that the code is being run from admin-ajax.php   
            }
        return ($query);     

}
```

Comment: You don't seem to define $pagenow

Comment: I did, and also I have logged what page is running the code and the code runs from admin-ajax.php

Comment: In your function posts_for_current_role, it looks as though $pagenow is undefined so your offending line never executes. Or am I not seeing something?

Comment: Sorry but to make things easier I didn't post all the function, but the global $pagenow is included. Should I post the whole function?

Comment: Andy I have loaded the complete code. Notice that there's a logging function to verify what page is applying the filter ad for 6 times it appears admin-ajax.php.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on my phone so hard to write a full code answer. Looks like the problem is that you are excluding anything written by user 1 from all Ajax queries. You could look at the wp_ajax_query_attachments hook instead which only fires in the context you want, I think.

Comment: Thanks Andy, seems working! But I would like to understand why admin-ajax.php could bypass all the conditions I wrote!!

Comment: Any Ajax call to WP will likely call admin-ajax.php as that's the way you're meant make Ajax calls. So your last condition will be true for many front end Ajax calls and then you're setting author -1 for all of those queries and excluding everything that user 1 has written.

Comment: If it's working then please do write up and accept your own answer as that keeps our site tidy and helps others with similar problems to yours.

Comment: I am posting the used code, but I would like you to publish it as you have suggested the solution! code:` if ( is_admin() && !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles )){
       add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'exclude_admin_media', 1, 1 );
}

function exclude_admin_media( $query ) 
{
  $query['author'] = '-1'; // exclude admin media
 return $query;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any ajax call to WP will likely call admin-ajax.php as that's the way you're meant to make ajax calls in WP. So your last condition will be true for many front end ajax calls and then you're setting author -1 for all of those queries and excluding everything that User #1, generally the default Admin user, has written.

It's probably better to use the wp_ajax_query_attachments hook instead which only fires in the context you want and so gives you a much more specific target for your query adjustment:

```
if ( is_admin() && !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) { 
    add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'exclude_admin_media', 1, 1 );
} 

function exclude_admin_media( $query ) { 

    $query['author'] = '-1'; 
    // exclude admin media 

    return $query; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Andy, but from an academical point of view, how could the admin-ajax.php make it  through the test strtolower($url_split[1]) == "wp-admin"), while in the front end?

Comment: Because that's where the file is: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.  admin-ajax.php does set a constant DOING_AJAX to true, so you can use that to exclude ajax calls in your logic.   As an aside, you can't generally rely on testing the file path like that and ought to get admin paths using admin_url().

Comment: Tell me more: if the code is running in the front-end the first part of the URI is not"wp-admin"...

Comment: While it might seem counter-intuitive, the preferred way of making ajax requests in the front end does call on the file `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` , as documented in https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins as well as most books on plugin development.